# CSV file not being imported by photoshop

Tags: csv, photoshop

Hi I'm trying to import a dataset to my photoshop, but I keep getting an error.

"could not parse the file contents as a data set. there were too many variable names in the first line of the text file."

I downloaded in csv and txt but neither works.
I did a simple sheet.

```
colour, item, description
red, ball, it is round
blue, rag, it is made of cotton
```

Comment: how is this related to google sheets?

Comment: the data was downloaded from google sheets, and maybe it's a sheets decryption problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't have spaces in data